# Flex Builder Tween Library

Tags: apache-flex, flash, graphics, adobe, action

There are missing tween libraries in my Flex Builder how to add them?

Sultan

Comment: Which SDK are you using?

Comment: I've been using Flex sdk 3 with Flex builder 3

Comment: Just add those to your library path of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=projects_7.html#157949

Add it to Library path.

Answer (score 1):

In Flex there are Move events for moving objects, but I don't think there are any extras you can add.

If you're looking for a good Tween library check out TweenLite: http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

Comment: I think we can add it to our library path of the project, if u r looking for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mx.effects.Tween for tweening. But i recommend using other tweening library like TweenLite, Tweener..etc.

Answer (score 0):

for adding the library in the flex/Flash builder project go to 
menue 
---> choose project 
---> choose properties (a window is open)
---->Select Flex Build path from left side 
----> Select libs from directory and add project(in case you have no swc) or add swc 
----> press OK
---- > clean /refresh your project.

you have done that!!!